# Как подставить число к строке в аргументе функции?

Tags: c++, строки, аргументы

Имеется функция

```
void lm(int mt, std::string msg);
```

Она принимает один числовой и строковый аргументы, но в программе требуется, что бы строковый элемент шёл с числовым. Как подставить число в данном случае к строке?

Т.е. должно что-то подобное получиться

```
int iResult;    
lm(1,"test message - "+iResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную проблему следующим образом:

```
lm(0, "FNU size is "+std::to_string(4));
```